# solving a PDE by first finding the solution to the steady-state

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am just wondering in the circled problem here
[image],

can I solve the problem by assuming there is a steady-solution and a transient solution? like this:

$v(x,t) = w_{\infty}(x) + k(x,t)$

It has the boundary condition of:

$v_x(0,t) = 0$,
$v_x(L,t) = 0$

And the initial condition of $v(x,0)= g(x)-h(x)$ (which are derived from couple lines above).

I was thinking of solving the v(x,t) by treating it as a heat equation with a steady-state solution and transient solution.

So I solve: $0 = w_{xx}(x) + 2a\alpha^2$ first (since steady-state solution means the $v_t$ already is zero, i.e. the $v_t$ in equation 20.4). (The $w_{xx}(x)$ is second derivative with respect to x. So w(x) or $w_{\infty}(x)$ is the steady-solution  (they are the same, I just use different notation so $w(x) = w_{\infty}(x)$ just want to stress it is when times already in infinity).

So I have the following steps:

$A = \alpha^2 w_x(x) + 2a\alpha^2x$

$Ax + B = \alpha^2 w(x) + a\alpha x^2$

So $w(x) = \frac{Ax+B-a\alpha x^2}{\alpha^2}$

Then to get A, B: I go with the condition that $v_x(0,t) = 0$,
$v_x(L,t) = 0$. So since the steady-state w(x) would satisfy the boundary condition,
so it means $0=v_x(0) = w_{\infty x}(0)$ and $0=v_x(L) = w_{\infty x}(L)$. So the steady-state solution will satisfy the inhomogeneous boundary condition.

So from my equation of $w(x)$, I have $w_x(x)= \frac{A-2a\alpha x}{\alpha^2}$, so $w_x(0)=0$ implies $A=0$. So now $w(x) = \frac{B-a\alpha x^2}{\alpha^2}$ as A is found to be $0$. Now to find B,  I make use of the other boundary condition (i.e. $w_x(L) = 0$). So I have $w_x(x) = \frac{-2a\alpha x}{\alpha^2}$ and set it equal to zero when $x=L$, so $0 = \frac{-2a\alpha L}{\alpha^2}$. But where is my B now lol, it disappears. So does that mean B can be arbitrary number? ( I am trying to solve for it lol, but it is gone now). So now I got stuck that I am not able to determine the steady-state solution $w(x)$ as B is not determined yet.

Is it possible to know what went wrong with my steps or assumptions when treating the v(x,t) as having a steady-solution and a transient solution in solving for the overall PDE?

Comment: A few remarks: When you post images like this, you should always give the **source**. And your question would make a better impression without those “lol”.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the "lol", will avoid them in future. But I was just frustrated and confused, and typing "lol" help me relax a bit. But yes will definitely keep this in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a source term $2a \alpha^2$ and boundary conditions $v_x=0$ which correspond to insulated ends, there is no steady-state solution, unless $a$ happens to be zero; the total heat energy in the rod will keep increasing if $a>0$ or decreasing if $a<0$.

This should be clear if you compare to the previous solution of the same problem in Example 18.2 (which I managed to [find](http://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Eward/teaching/m316/lecture18.pdf) with a bit of googling).

Comment: @Lundamark  Thank you for the quick response. Oh, so the assumption of steady solution is not correct and that's why the approach I assumed is not even correct and the weird result. Thank you for pointing out the mistakes.

Comment: But I just want to ask another question, when trying to solve this kind of PDE problem. Is it true that there is some "guessing" game or approach going on here? Such as when people try to break down the problem into smaller problem by writing something like $u(x,t) = w(x) + v(x,t) $ or $u(x,t)= w(x,t) + v(x,t)$. Is it mainly based on experience or some educated guess? when we break the problems like that? So apparently I didn't "break-down" the problem correctly, that's why my approach doesn't work. Is it correct?

Comment: Well, you build up a repertoire of methods, and for a given problem you try whatever method you think is going to work, often guided by the physical interpretation. One useful idea is to try to reduce the problem to a simpler one that you know how to handle. I would say it's part recipe, part experience, and part guessing.